What is the reason Kendall's car does not have a frontal license plate displayed?
In the TV show, Succession, season 1, ep 1, when Kendall travels in a car to a major merger negotiation in the city of New York CBD / downtown, I noticed the car he travels in does not have a frontal license plate displayed; while all other vehicles in the same scenes show frontal license plates, which are blurred for privacy reasons.

I did a google search on whether a frontal license plate is required in the city of New York, the answer is Yes.
So in the TV show, Succession, why does Kendall's ride not have a frontal license plate?

Because he doesn't care about the occasional ticket?

Was the rear plate a New York plate? If the car is registered in a state that does not require a front plate then you don’t have to magically add one when you drive to New York.

I'm not sure that is strictly true - I just read the relevant New York law and it concerns vehicles operated on New York roads, not just ones registered in New York.  However it does seem to be quite lax in its enforcement - probably because of out of state vehicles.

@iandotkelly It does appear that it's unclear whether you have to magically produce a front plate to avoid a ticket if you're driving a car registered in a state that only issues one plate into New York. I suspect in practice NY police might not be keen to issue tickets that could be reasonably contested so easily. Some states do exclude cars registered in states that only issue one plate from a front plate requirement, although New York doesn't appear to be one of those states. See: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/45821/legal-to-drive-a-car-without-front-tag-out-of-registered-state

I found a web site that shows screen shots of the back of Kendall's Mercedes S-Class from Season 1, Episode 1, and it does have a New York State rear license plate:

So Kendall is breaking the law. I suspect @Valorum has the right answer in suggesting he doesn't care about getting a ticket. While it's less likely that he would get pulled over only because of the lack of front plate, even if he did, I'm sure he can afford the fine.
What could be a severe consequence is if he committed a crime in the car, then the lack of front plate could enable the DA to add additional charges relating to evading arrest or something by attempting to hide his car's registration. This isn't the law stack, so that's just supposition. Outside of that possibility, it's just not a serious enough violation for a wealthy person to worry about too much, especially when the car looks so cool without a front plate.

would it be possible that the TV show does not want to provide any license plate so that no one would be searching for its owner.

@YuZhang If that were the intention of the producers then they messed up badly by showing the rear license plate.

Great answer.  From my reading around this it is even common for less rich people to 'risk it' and not put a plate on the front of a car for aesthetic reasons - perhaps carrying the plate in the car ready to put it in the front window to persuade the police that they were doing their best, and will 'for sure'' attach it right away.  So it seems enforcement is quite lax.

@YuZhang not at likely.  It seems that this plate has been used multiple times on multiple vehicles on movies and tv.  You can see GHO-7561 here for its appeances in just ONE tv show: https://personofinterest.fandom.com/wiki/License_Plates_of_Interest

That Person of Interest Wiki asserts that they check with the NY DMV for unused plate numbers, but I have no way of confirming that.  In some other states they have reserved plate ranges for movie and TV production.

Is it Kendall breaking the law, or his driver?

@AakashM Not really relevant to film or TV appreciation but the places I’ve lived the ticket goes to the operator when the car is pulled over and the responsibility of the registered owner if it’s ticketed while parked.
